# Bookkeeping report doesn't record check number for financial account/type

Tags: civireport, financial-types, reports, financial-accounts

Every day we have to print off a report on the checks (their check numbers, name of payee, etc) we have received and their respective financial account credit codes.

However, the bookkeeping report built into civiCRM is not recording the check numbers.

[image: checknumber not appearing]

**UPDATE:** It only shows the check number if the account debit is the 1100 ASSET "Deposit Bank Account" financial account that comes default with civiCRM. How do I make sure that the debit account is not accounted twice (as in checks only go into the Deposit Bank Asset and not Accounts Receivable as in the first example which is done correctly)? See new picture below: 
[image: depositbankasset]