# Check numbers in reports

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, civireport, contributions

My client took great pains to record check numbers and payment amounts and wants to produce an event payment report which includes the check numbers associated with each registration. I can get everything in the report except the check numbers. I have confirmed that the check numbers are entered, they just aren't appearing the report.  I've done this with standard reports and extended reports and the output is roughly the same. They need this report for their board. Any ideas of how we get there from here?

I did look at [Bookkeeping report doesn't record check number for financial account/type](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/bookkeeping-report-doesnt-record-check-number-for-financial-account-type) but I'm not sure that it's the same issue and that item was never resolved that I see.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround might be to run the contribution detail report filtering to event fees and select columns Source and Check Number, then do an excel vlookup() to cross-reference Source against the Event name in the event participants list (which I'm guessing is the report you're looking at).

Comment: That's a great idea, but I don't see a filter for the events. It almost feels like I'm closer, but I don't really have a final report.

Comment: Event is the `source` field in the contribution detail.